# Entire device(embedded device) reboot after receiving same buffer few hundreds times

Tags: python, c, sockets, embedded

I have following situation.
My system(actually it's an embedded system) has usual TCP stack. It opens socket, bind, listen, accept and receive. Usual set. When there is incoming data, system process data and sends the response. Sounds simple. On other side I have a tester, which is sending different sets of data. One of tests - send data and NOT WAITING for response, send again after sleep of 1 second. And then again, again... 10K times.

**Problem**: After few hundreds of times, my system(embedded) fails and reboot.

I assume there is incoming buffer overflow. But I did not find how to resolve this issue.

I need an assistance. Somebody...

**Environment**: Embedded system: running VxWorks and application is written on C language Tester: run under Windows and written on Python.

```
int tcp_server(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;                  /* server's socket address */
    int sockAddrSize;                               /* size of socket address structure */
    int status = STATUS_OK, option = 1;
    SOCKET server_socket;


        keep_servicing = 1;
        /* set up the local address */
        sockAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        memset((void *) &serverAddr, 0, sockAddrSize);
        serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT_NUM);
        serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        /* create a TCP-based socket */
        /* ixlog("About to create TCP socket"); */
        server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_IPPROTO_IP);
        if (server_socket == SOCKET_INVALID_SOCKET) {
            ixerr_d("socket error: %d", socket_errno());
            return SOCKET_INVALID_SOCKET;
        }
        g_server_socket = server_socket;

 
        /* bind socket to local address */
        status = socket_bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sockAddrSize);
        if (status == STATUS_ERR_SOCKET) {
            ixerr_d("3. socket_bind error: %d", socket_errno());
            socket_close(server_socket);
            return status;
        }


        /* create queue for client connection requests */
        status = socket_listen(server_socket, SERVER_MAX_CONNECTIONS);
        if (status == STATUS_ERR_SOCKET) {
            ixerr_d("Error listening, error no.=%d", socket_errno());
            socket_close(server_socket);
            return STATUS_ERR_SOCKET;
        }

        while (keep_servicing) {
            status = tcp_server_loop_body(server_socket);
            if (STATUS_ERR_REINIT == status) {
                keep_servicing = 0;
                reinit_tcp_server = 1;
                break;
            }
            if (status != STATUS_OK) {
                /* if( STATUS_EXIT == status || STATUS_ERR_SOCKET == status ) { */
                if (STATUS_EXIT == status) {
                    ixlog("Exit from loop");
                    keep_servicing = 0;
                } else {
                    ixerr_d("Error from loop: %d", status);
                }
            }
            if (!keep_servicing && !update_app) {
                socket_close(server_socket);
                g_server_socket = 0;
                status = revive_tcp_server();
                if (STATUS_OK == status) {
                    keep_servicing = 1;
                }
            }
        }

    socket_close( server_socket );
    gRevive = 1;
    return status;
}

static int tcp_server_loop_body( int server_socket )
{
    int status = STATUS_OK;
    SOCKET session_socket, local_server_socket = server_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr; /* client's socket address */
    struct MESSAGE message;
    int sockAddrSize;                     /* size of socket address structure */
    int end_of_message = 0;
    char* read_ptr;
    int remainig_buffer_size = 0;
    size_t slen = 0, dlen = 0, len = 0;
    unsigned char aesKey[16];
    int pre_flag = 0;
    int out_len = 0;
    int length = 0;
    static int messages = 0;


    removal_flag = 0;
    message.resp_buffer = NULL;
    COPY_BUFFERS(aesKey, g_OUTAesSessionKeyShared ,AES_SIZE);
    memset( &message, 0, sizeof(message) );
    sockAddrSize = sizeof( clientAddr );

    /*ixlog( "calling accept ..."); */
    session_socket = socket_accept( server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &sockAddrSize);
    if( session_socket == STATUS_ERR_SOCKET)
    {
        int err = socket_errno( );
        if( err == ERR_CONNABORTED ) {
            /* ixlog( "connection aborted" ); */
            return STATUS_EXIT;
        }
        else {
            ixerr_d( "Error accepting, error no.=%d", err );
            return STATUS_ERR_REINIT;
        }
    }
    if (session_socket == SOCKET_INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        int err = socket_errno();
        if (err != ERR_SOCKET_EWOULDBLOCK)
        {
            socket_close(server_socket);
            reinit_tcp_server = 1;
            return STATUS_ERR_SOCKET;
        }
    }



    read_ptr = request_buffer;
    memset(read_ptr, 0x00, REQUEST_BUFFER_SIZE);
    remainig_buffer_size = REQUEST_BUFFER_SIZE;

    while( !end_of_message )
    {
        length = 0;


        length = socket_recv(session_socket, read_ptr, remainig_buffer_size, 0);
        if( length <= 0 )
        {
            ixerr_d( "0. Error receiving: %d", socket_errno() );
            ixerr_d( "0. Error receiving: Length = %d", length );
            socket_close( session_socket );
            ixerr_d( "0. close socket= %d", session_socket );
            return STATUS_ERR_SOCKET;
        }
        else
        {
            remainig_buffer_size -= length;
            if (0 >= remainig_buffer_size)
            {
                ixerr( "Check the system. It can be under attack");
                socket_close( session_socket );
                return STATUS_ERR_BUFFERFULL;
            }
            read_ptr += length;
            len += length;
            if ( MSG_TERMINATOR == (*(read_ptr - 1)) ) {
                end_of_message = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    process_message(read_ptr);

    socket_send(response_ptr);
}
```

You can assume, that all unknown functions and variables are global.

Comment: Receivers must drop packets when buffers are full.

Comment: Is this default behavior or I need to set this option ?

Comment: Depends on your TCP stack.

Comment: And how can I check it ?

Comment: Track down where it's crashing

Comment: If your MCU has a reset reason in some register check this after startup. Depending on the reason dig further. Find out what OS function may initiate a reset, set a breakpoint and check from where this function gets called. I'm not sure, but I think there is no guarantee that you will always find `MSG_TERMINATOR` as the last byte of one receive operation. A TCP connection is a stream. There may be buffering involved. I don't see any code that prevents your receive loop from writing past the end of the buffer in case a message is too long or if the terminaor is not found as expected.

Comment: What is `process_message` and how long does it take? I notice you have some AES code. That can be computationally intensive. Can you elide the packet processing and do you still see the crash? Can you reduce the sender wait time to force the crash to happen sooner (seconds instead of hours)? Can you attach a packet sniffer such as wireshark? Can you do hires timestamping similar to clock_gettime? Can you config the socket with more/larger kernel buffers?

Comment: You are doing `process_message(read_ptr);` but at that point it is pointing past the end of the message data. And you're not passing a length. So, is the posted code the real code?

Comment: I realize you're on VxWorks but can you do (the equivalent of) the FIONREAD ioctl to see how much data is pent up? This should be about the same most times. If you see it creep up, this means you're losing ground and that your packet processing can't keep up with the data rate in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved.
I have edited the question. Added last line

```
socket_send(response_ptr);
```

This change had to be in code from the beginning.

But the solution is simple:

After line:

```
socket_send(response_ptr);
```

Added delay of 50 msec

```
wait(50);
```